# Where to get username/password for JSch connecting to AWS EC2?

Tags: java, ssh, amazon-ec2, sftp, jsch

I am trying to connect to EC2 instance with the following Java code:

```
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
Session session = jSch.getSession(username, EC2-IP, 22);
session.setPassword(password);
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect();
```

In EC2 IAM web console I created an user/password and I can use it to login to AWS management console. But when I use this user/password in the above Java code, I receive:

```
Error: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
```

Comment: Do not use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`. You are losing security by doing so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH/SFTP username for Amazon EC2 is:

- For an Amazon Linux AMI, the user name is `ec2-user`.
- For a RHEL AMI, the user name is `ec2-user` or `root`.
- For an Ubuntu AMI, the user name is `ubuntu` or `root`.
- For a Centos AMI, the user name is `centos`.
- For a Fedora AMI, the user name is `ec2-user`.
- For SUSE, the user name is `ec2-user` or `root`.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

---

To authenticate, use a private key that you have associated with the instance, when you were creating the instance.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html

---

In general, you should first setup and test connection with some standalone SFTP/SSH client. And only then try to connect with your code.

I have written a guide for [connecting to Amazon EC2 with WinSCP SFTP client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html). If you follow it and make a successful connection with WinSCP, it should be then easy to do the same with JSch code.

Comment: Do I have to use ec2-key-pair (the .pem file) when using Jsch? There is no way to connect just use user/password?

Comment: That's the best way. But if you want, you can allow a password authentication for sure. You have to login to the server using the key though first, because that's initially the only way. Anyway, you are getting more and more off-topic here. This is not a programming question anymore.

Comment: I am writing a Java program to simulate Filezilla FTP which only require user/password. I know Apache net package can do that. I am trying to make Jsch to do it (connect only using user/password)

Comment: Sorry, that does not make sense. With the default EC2 setup, you cannot use username/password to authenticate to EC2, no matter what client software or library you are using. So what is it that you are trying to simulate? - If you can connect with FileZilla using a username/password to over SSH/SFTP, then you can do the same using JSch. Then I do not understand, what is your question about. You must know what username/password are you using in FileZilla.

Comment: And Apache Net library does not support SFTP/SSH! Aren't you actually using FTP(S) in FileZilla and/or Apache Net? That's a completely different protocol!

Comment: Sorry I did not describe it clearly. I am making my  program both FTP and SFTP. So I guess I should use Jsch for SFTP and Apache Net for FTP. Thanks for your help.